# Can all infected types be exposed to finishers?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

So default roaches seem to be able to be exposed to finishers in multiple ways:

- From the front if they haven't mutated yet
- From the back regardless of mutation/awareness
- When downed
- When exposed to stun/flash grenades

Breachers also can be exposed to finishers if they're caught unaware of you.

I also know that the Smasher can be exposed to melee finishers if he charges a wall and is stunned temporarily, but I'm curious if Rooters and Apex types can be exposed to finishers at well. Sometimes it feels like I'm not fighting them correctly if I'm just expending an entire LMG clip into them over and over.

Are all infected types able to be exposed to finishers? Or is it just roaches, breachers, and the Smasher?